# c# .net добавить значение в лист с кол-ом колонок > 1 из одного листа в другой

Tags: c#, .net, list

имеется 2 класса и 2 их листа

```
    первый
    List<NSKData> NSKDataList = new List<NSKData>();

    public class NSKData
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Авария { get; set; }
        public string ToolTipInfoText { get; set; }
        public NSKData() { }
        public NSKData(string id, string авария, string tooltipinfo)
        {
            ID = id;
            Авария = авария;
            ToolTipInfoText = tooltipinfo;
        }
    }


     второй
     List<IssuesMoreInfo> IssuesMoreInfoList = new List<IssuesMoreInfo>();

    public class IssuesMoreInfo
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string СутьАварии { get; set; }
    }
```

Их данные заполняются не одновременно, т.е. возможно получить только сначала один, потом второй, или наоборот, это не суть, важно то что одновременно нельзя - иначе бы я не задавал данный вопрос.

Вопрос заключается в том как получив данные в первый и второй, передать из второго (IssuesMoreInfoList) данные СутьАварии в первый, в поле ToolTipInfoText, согласно ID в обоих, т.е. если ID в первом = 10, получаем СутьАварии во втором по ID 10, и передаём в первый.

Искал в интернете инфу, нашёл метод Insert для List'ов, но я не могу передать больше одного параметра, т.е. ощущение что это создавалось для листов с одной колонкой, возможно я ошибаюсь в чём то.

Можно ещё как вариант слепить каким-то макаром третий лист содержащий всю инфу из первого и второго, но хотелось бы просто дополнить первый и передать в него информацию аля:
NSKDataList.Insert(index, id , Авария, СутьАварии) , в таком духе

Заранее спасибо...

Comment: вопрос решился `var infoIdLookup = IssuesMoreInfoList.ToLookup(i => i.ID);
foreach(NSKData data in NSKDataList)
{
    data.ToolTipInfoText = infoIdLookup[data.ID]
       .Select(i => i.IssueMoreInfoText)
       .FirstOrDefault();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал как то так:

```
  var withoutInfo = NSKDataList.Where(n => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.ToolTipInfoText)).ToList();
  foreach (var info in IssuesMoreInfoList)
  {
    var copy = withoutInfo.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == info.ID);
    if (copy != null)
      copy.ToolTipInfoText = info.СутьАварии;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

можно решить через linq или так:

```
var infoIdLookup = IssuesMoreInfoList.ToLookup(i => i.ID);
foreach(NSKData data in NSKDataList)
{
    data.ToolTipInfoText = infoIdLookup[data.ID]
        .Select(i => i.IssueMoreInfoText)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```